# How to design bar chart in c

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements, bar-chart

I have created the program and generate code below

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main(){    
> int a,i;    
> scanf("%d",&a);
> while(a!=-1){
> if(a>=0 && a<=80){
> for(i=a;i<=a;i++)
> printf("|");
> printf("%d\n");
> scanf("%d",&a);
> }           
> }
> ```

with input 1 3 4 4 5 5 -1, it should be display a bar chart like

|

| | |

| | | |

| | | |

| | | | |

| | | | |

but in that codes ,display 
|

|

|

|

|

|

can anybody explain why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=a;i<=a;i++)
      ^ maybe you want 0 here?
```

`printf("%d\n");` also looks wrong, `%d` is a formate string uses to print value of `int`. To print simply newline char it should be just `printf("\n");`

Comment: you're right,it works.but can i put any number in there? why it necessarry?

Comment: Given what you want it to look like above, I think you just want printf("\n");

Comment: @user160247 Suppose you have a viable like `int i = 10;` and you wants to prints its value then you need `%d` as `printf("i value is = %d", i);`. But What we can understand from your code you don't wanted to print any int value that is why `%d` is redundant. I suggest you to pick some good book from  [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)